# JPG подключенный через css не отображается в проекте Django2.2, сам же css подключен

Tags: css, python-3.x, django, html5, jpeg

у меня проблема следующая, создана папка static/images (jpg файл находится тут), static/css(css файл тут), в общем ситуация следующая, файл html и css подтягиваются без проблем, jpg прописан в css что бы был адаптивным и он не подтягивается, а если прописываю в html он подтягивается, но перестает быть адаптивным, 2 дня пытался самостоятельно решить проблему, не получилось, по этому нужен хелп.{% load static %} прописан выше документ html

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang ="en">
   <head>
<meta charset ="UTF-8">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Berkshire+Swash&family=Galada&display=swap&family=Kaushan+Script&family=Special+Elite&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Сrown will</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href= "{% static 'css/style.css' %}" >
</head>









.intro {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: center;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100vh;
   background: url("images/intro.jpg")
   center
   no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

в settings настройки прописаны, css отображается jpg нет, путь прописан верный. так как через браузер отображается как задумано, подскажите пожалуйста

---

проблему я так и не решил, сделал всё что предложили в ответах, не получилось, версия Django 2.2

Answer (score 1):

у тебя css подключается через  {% static 'css/style.css' %}, а изображение в css просто "images/intro.jpg", если ты говоришь, что изображение расположено в папке статик, то скорее  всего вызов нужно делать "static/images/intro.jpg", если не так, то просто пропиши путь до него так, что бы было с учетом того места где у тебя хранятся статические файлы

Comment: сделал как вы указали, так же не отображается jpg файл

Comment: в строке браузера пропиши путь до нужного изображения и добавь этот путь в css

Comment: вот сейчас не понял, можете по подробней описать сам процесс, пожалуйста

Comment: самый простой способ, вставь изображение в html (вместо css), если оно отображается, скопируй путь до него и вставь этот путь в css

Comment: я уже так поступал, в css оно не отображается, в Html отображается, но перестает быть адаптивным

Answer (score 1):

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href= "{% static 'css/style.css' %}" >
```

Если это есть, тогда ничего не остается, как корректировать url в CSS файле и указать правильный путь до изображения.

```
background: center no-repeat url("../images/intro.jpg");
```

или

```
background-image: center no-repeat url("images/intro.jpg");
background-image: center no-repeat url("../images/intro.jpg");
```